# Change ownership of linux directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I'm very new to Linux..

Once I have changed ownership of `/usr` my `sudo` command failed working ..

Once I changed ownership of `/var` some other things broke ..

1: I just want to know which are folders where one should never change it's default ownership..

2:   what if someone gets `permission_denied` for `/var` during installing some packages .. `chmod` or `chown` should be used ...

Comment: You should actually _never_ change the file ownership of system resources.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't mess with the permissions of files and directories installed by the OS and package manager.

Comment: If someone wants to store a file to a location where the permission is denied, then you should think the other way 'round: _why_ is permission denied. The answer is _not_ "because of file ownerships", but "because that is not where that user is meant to write to". Installation of things into a system should only be done by the system administration account, so `root`. Everyone else needs to either use the private "home" folder each account has (that is what that account actually is for), or he needs to assume another user role, for example by means of the `sudo ` utility.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and belongs over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score 0):

I would never change the ownership in folders unlike /home/* /opt/*. Sometimes you have to change the owner if you put your own stuff to /etc/*, but you should now what to do.

To install software, even in Ubuntu use the provided tools, 'apt' and 'dpkg' for example. Often the installation needs root rights. Give them with the usage of and additional 'sudo'.

```
# f.e. installation of a command line browser
sudo apt install w3m
```